# Ubuntu Core - "EFI sub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path"

Tags: boot, uefi, ubuntu-core

First of all, I'm new to Linux in general. I did try searching on here but was unable to find anything, but then again, I'm also relatively new to using SO other than stumbling across here via Google. Hopefully I've provided enough information below but please let me know if not.

I need a simple web kiosk for a hobby project, and stumbled across [this article](https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk) that utilises Ubuntu Core + Ubuntu Frame.

Though I'm not sure if it's relevant, the hardware I'm using are bits that I had lying around:

- **MB** - ASUS Prime Z270-A
- **CPU** - Intel Celeron G3930
- **RAM** - Crucial RAM 4GB DDR4 2400MHz
- **SSD** - Crucial P2 250GB M.2 PCIe Gen3 NVMe

After Googling around, I found [this article](https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc) that outlines how to install Ubuntu Core on Intel NUCs. Although my setup isn't an Intel NUC, I thought the process should be applicable in my case, so I followed it.

The installation seems to work and the web kiosk does indeed run, however it takes a long time to boot. Each time I boot, I'm seeing the following:

```
/EndEntire
/EndEntire
EFI sub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path
```

After about 30 seconds to a minute, the above screen will disappear and it appears to boot correctly.

I assume there's something wrong with my boot/UEFI configuration, but am unsure what the above means and where to look. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!